# jQuery finding the item id

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to show,
specific items, by finding the "id" number.
however, the code keeps getting an error on "id"

onClick Code:

```
<li id="item-4" class="ui-state-default" data-type="text" onclick="onClickCard(this)">
Text 03<img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/>
</li>
```

The id code:

```
<div id="item-4" class="well textPreview previews">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h2>03: Text</h2>
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="20" maxlength="500">
   500 words only..
</textarea>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
var onClickCard = function(dst){    
var t = $(dst).attr('id') 
//cant find "id"

$('.previews').hide();
var q = '#' + t;
$(q).show();
};
```

Comment: where is onClickCard called?

Comment: <div id='item-"5" should be <div id="item-5"

Comment: it should be `<div id='item-5' class="well textPreview previews">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here quotes are messing it up:

```
<div id='item-"5"
```

change it to:

```
<div id='item-5' ....>
```

---

Little more updates:

```
var onClickCard = function(dst){    
     var t = dst.id;

     $('.previews').hide();
      var q = '.' + t; // change to class
      $(q).show();
};
```

And the markup for div:

```
<div class='item-5' ....>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that is just a mistype. Must have copied the code wrong.

Comment: But still that is an invalid markup due to same id placed to two different elems in a single page. IDs must be unique per element.

Comment: Oh, good point. I have two lists, that essential show the same item, therefore I tried to use the same id.

Comment: Instead if possible change div's id to className and with less work you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` and `div` have the same id. That's why he errors, you can't have duplicate id's.

```
<li id="item-4" class="ui-state-default" data-type="text" onclick="onClickCard(this)">
Text 03<img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/>
</li>
<div id="item-4" class="well textPreview previews"></div>
```

change it to something like

```
<li id="li-item-4" class="ui-state-default" data-type="text" onclick="onClickCard(this)">
Text 03<img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/>
</li>
<div id="item-4" class="well textPreview previews"></div>
```

Comment: The two lists are essentially the same item. Any brief suggestions on how to change the code?

Comment: you can't have the same id twice in your html page, that just isn't valid html. I'm working on a plnkr.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you want to do. But why not just specify the specific ID?
Like this:

```
var t = $(dst).attr('#item-4')
```

Or if you want to target a spcific div do this: http://jsfiddle.net/384cP/1/
(or this if you want li: http://jsfiddle.net/384cP/2/)